# margin-bottom not working on simple layout

Tags: html, css, margin

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/amit78523/pen/VwQdOzZ) for demonstration. The layout is very simple, with no absolute position or float.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <main>
    <section></section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

I am expecting the `section` to have a margin on all sides but bottom margin is not showing. Am I doing anything wrong?

One solution would be to set the `height: calc(100% - 0.5rem);` on section. But if I do that, what's the point of having `margin-bottom` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply implement this with border 0.5rem.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {}

section {  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100wh;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 0.5rem solid yellow;
  background: gray;  
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <main>
      <section>Hello Amit Kumar!</section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: okay.... after your answer I understood my mistake. margin bottom is present but could not be seen because of overflow hidden. I feel so stupid now!